# Ошибка при добавлении нового пользователя

Tags: mongodb, centos

При попытке добавить нового пользователя, используя команду **db.createUser**, получаю ошибку:

> 2015-03-05T20:29:10.639+0200 E QUERY
> Error: couldn't add user: No role
> named userAdminAnyDatabase@test23s
>     at Error (<anonymous>)
>     at DB.createUser (src/mongo/shell/db.js:1066:11)
>     at (shell):1:4 at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1066

Для добавления использую команду:

```
db.createUser( { user: "admin94",
           pwd: "14336546545",
           roles: [ {role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db:
 "test23s"}] } )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Error: couldn't add user: No role named userAdminAnyDatabase@test23s
```

*This*

Узнай какие роли у тебя есть вообще для начала: `db.getRoles()`

Или попробуй так:

```
db.createUser(
{
  user: "admin94",
  pwd: "14336546545",
  roles: [
     { role: "readWrite", db: "test23s" }
         ]
     }
)
```

---

```
db.createRole(
   {
     role: "mongostatRole",
     privileges: [
       { resource: { cluster: true }, actions: [ "serverStatus" ] }
     ],
     roles: []
   }
)
```

Comment: 
> > db.getRoles()
> [ ]

Comment: Ну вот и ответ, вы пытаетесь использовать роль, которой нету.
Вот подробный офф ман от том, как создать роль: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/define-roles/

Т.е. примерно вот так можно сделать

Дополнил ответ